# how to pass a parameter into jquery UI dialog box

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I have several links on my page and each one contains a different `id=X`. I want to open a dialog box when user clicks on any of these links and also want the `id` value of the link that was clicked. Using this ID I need to go back to my server and fetch a page into the dialog box using ajax.

My first step was to try to get the ID into the dialog box. So, I created a sample: http://jsbin.com/ajefel/1/

The dialog box opens up, however, I don't know how to get access to the `id` value of the clicked link into the dialog box.

**Question**

In the [example above](http://jsbin.com/ajefel/1/), how can I include the value of the clicked link inside the dialog box?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass reference to sender to your function:

```
<a href="#?id=3" onclick="return showDialog(this)">
```

Modify the function to accept sender as parameter:

```
function showDialog(sender){
   // TODO
   alert(sender);
}
```

PS: Avoid inline javascript when possible..

See your modified [JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/ajefel/3/).

Comment: This will get the link into the showDialog function, however, how do I further pass it down to the jquery UI dialog box?

Comment: I want to pass it down to the `$("#divId").dialog`

Comment: See the jsbin, you can update content of the div. Or do you want something more?

Comment: please see the update you the jsbin link you sent: http://jsbin.com/ajefel/8/ If you look at the source, when user clicks the link to open the dialog box, I want to open a new page, `sample.htm`, in this case. I want to pass the id to `sample.htm`. So when link with id 3 is clicked the request is made to `sample.htm?id=3` and when link with id 4 is clicked the request is made to `sample.htm?id=4`

Comment: Basically you need to see how to trigger the dialog alternatively. You're initializing the dialog box on document load, now you want to change the source dynamically, so you will have to initialize the dialog dynamically with the dynamic source.